# NSLocalizedString does not recognize Localizable.strings strings

Tags: swift, string, localization, localizable.strings

I'm trying to use the swift string localization system, but apparently it does not recognize the strings, for example instead of appearing the string inicio appears txtinicio, I'm trying to access the strings like this:

```
NSLocalizedString("txtinicio", comment: "")
```

My settings look like this:

[image: image 1]

My strings file is with the strings like this:

```
"txtinicio" = "Início";
```

String file configuration looks like this:

image2

[image: image2]

image3

[image: image3]

image 4

[image: image4]

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem definitively, what was happening and that in the framework that I was using it used localizable, and used the default file Localizable.strings, in my project the file of strings also had that name, the solution was to change the name of the strings file in my project, it worked